# Using putty, Left and Right keys move cursor one word, instead of one char

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zle

I have looked for a solution to this `OhMyZSH!` problem for a few days now, but can't find a solution.
Admittedly, I do not understand how `zle` really works, same for `bindkey`. Same goes for the way terminal emulators send "control sequences", and what the "terminal type" means (`xterm`, versus `xterm-256-color`, and others). Same for the "Application mode"

### The setup

I have 2 machines where the latest version of OhMyZSH is installed, commit `c3b072`:

- machine A: SLES 11 SP4, running `zsh 4.3.6 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`
- machine B: Ubuntu 16.04, running `zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)`

I connect to either machine using Putty running on Windows, with terminal type `xterm`, and in UTF-8 translation mode.

My `zshrc` files are pretty much vanilla `OhMyZSH` templates, I have just changed the prompt to `dieter` on machine A, and `powerlevel-9k` [https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k] on machine B.

### What I observe on machine A (aka the "bad" one)

When I edit my command line, the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> cursor keys move one whole word (instead of 1 single character).

<kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys though, bring the cursor to the beginning and end of the line, as expected.

This described behaviour applies when in `emacs` mode (`bindkey -e`).

When I go to `vim` mode (`bindkey -v`), the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> arrows move 1 character, but the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys don't move the cursor to the beginning and end of the line. Instead, they switch the case of the character under the cursor.

### What I observe on machine B (aka the "good" one)

<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keys move the cursor one single char. Home and end keys move the cursor to the beginning and end of line resp. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> combos bring my cursor to the beginning and end resp.

This is the behaviour I would like for all my shells.

### What I have found so far

I think it is a `bindkey` issue. But I know next to nothing about that, and I've had a hard time finding any doc on this `zsh` built-in.

Running `zsh -v` on both machines at login time gives very different results, despite similar `.zshrc` files.

Could someone explain to me what is causing these 2 machines to behave so differently, and how I can change my configuration so that consistency is regained, and all my shells behave like on machine B (aka the "good" one)?

I'm sure you will let me know if you need more information that I don't know is needed.

Many thanks

Comment: You might want to include the output of your `zsh -v` in your question.

Comment: `zsh -v` traces have been added to this gist: https://gist.github.com/guneemwelloeux/34ee3943ac32847895dc4c57f74c5ff7. Careful though, the files are 6k lines long each, so the page is pretty heavy to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must configure your terminal type as [`putty`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty), [`putty-256color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-256color), or [`putty-sco`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#tic-putty-sco) when using PuTTY.  They are the only terminal types whose entries in the terminfo database *correctly describe PuTTY*.

It is a widespread *incorrect* assumption that terminal emulators are all compatible with XTerm, and that the `xterm` and `xterm-256color` entries in the terminfo database correctly describe them.

This erroneous thinking [is called out in Thomas Dickey's XTerm FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#other_versions-id) and it is worth observing that the `xterm` and `xterm-256color` entries do not even describe all versions of XTerm, let alone other terminal emulators.

PuTTY's doco such as the page hyperlinked there by M. Dickey, even today [16 years since the `putty` entry was added to terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.ti.html#t20011117), unfortunately promotes this mis-use of the `xterm` terminal type, but a mis-use it is, and this is the very sort of application misbehaviour that occurs.

Comparing the terminfo database entries for `xterm-256color` and `putty-256color` reveals what is happening with your <kbd>⇱ Home</kbd> and <kbd>⇲ End</kbd> keys:

```
% infocmp xterm-256color putty-256color|grep -F kend
    kend: '\EOF', '\E[4~'.
% infocmp xterm-256color putty-256color|grep -F khome
    khome: '\EOH', '\E[1~'.
%
```

As you can see, an application that is told that it is dealing with XTerm expects to receive (from the terminal) the control sequence `␛OH` for the <kbd>⇱ Home</kbd> key and the control sequence `␛OF` for the <kbd>⇲ End</kbd> key.  But PuTTY actually sends the control sequences `␛[1~` and `␛[4~` (respectively) instead.

Your application, the Z shell, expecting the the XTerm keyboard control sequences (because you have erroneously told it that your terminal has the type `xterm`), does not recognize the PuTTY control sequences, and in fact breaks them down into the `vi`-mode commands to exit insert mode (`␛`) and swap the case of the current character (`~`).

## Further reading

- [Where does the TERM environment variable default get set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/)
- [Fish shell shows dark-grey "âŽ" characters in prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287465/)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444270/5132

Comment: Thank you for the very useful information. After setting `TERM` to `putty-256-color` in putty, I could get Home and End to work as I expect. However the arrows still move by one word. Ctrl+arrow moves by one character though. And then, when I start `tmux`, the Home+arrow combos move by one word again...

Comment: PuTTY's arrow/control-arrow switches the sent-sequence between *normal* and *application* modes.  The difference you're commenting on has to do with how the terminal was initialized.  After changing `TERM`, you might get more consistent behavior by running **`reset`**.

Comment: Out of tmux, `reset` helped: arrows move by one char, Ctrl +  arrows move by one word. Running tmux though, I can only get "move by one word" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As kindly pointed by JdeBP, my `TERM` was wrongly set.

I was finally able to have everything working consistently with the following steps:

1. Set terminal type in Putty to `putty`
2. Deactivate application mode for cursor and keypad in Putty
3. Add the following lines to my `.tmux.conf` file

   - `set -g default-terminal "$TERM"` to prevent tmux from using `screen` by default
   - `set -g terminal-overrides "putty*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"` to have the <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keys move by one char, instead of one word